# I can't lower the fan speed on my Nvidia X Server Settings

Tags: nvidia, fan, 21.10

I'm a bit of a Ubuntu newbie, but I feel like I'm getting the hang of things.

I can't however seem to lower the speed of my GPU fan. The computer has no problem at all running at lower temp, and it seems to me that the fan in exessively fast right now.

When I go to the Nvidia settings there is an option to lower the fan speed. But when I lower it and hit 'Apply', it resets to it's default 30.

Any ideas why this is? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Since you are using Nvidia settings to do this that is a question to ask Nvidia.

Comment: Over in the Related section to the right, there is this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394342/i-cant-lower-the-fan-speed-on-my-nvidia-x-server-settings#:~:text=Nvidia%20X%20Server%20Settings%20is%20not%20saving%20the%20settings

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. `cd /./etc/X11/`
2. `sudo -s` [because you need root access]
3. `gedit Xwrapper.config &`
4. add the line `needs_root_rights=yes` before `allowed_users=console`.

Therefore the `Xwrapper.config` file will be:

```
# Xwrapper.config (Debian X Window System server wrapper configuration file)
#
# This file was generated by the post-installation script of the
# xserver-xorg-legacy package using values from the debconf database.
#
# See the Xwrapper.config(5) manual page for more information.
#
# This file is automatically updated on upgrades of the xserver-xorg-legacy
# package *only* if it has not been modified since the last upgrade of that
# package.
#
# If you have edited this file but would like it to be automatically updated
# again, run the following command as root:
#   dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-legacy
needs_root_rights=yes
allowed_users=console
```